# I keep getting only the first item in my recyclerview but in the logcat i get them all

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

Here is my code *(I think the problem is in **notifydatasetchanged** and where it should be put)*:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

CollectionReference db1=db.collection("Joboffers");

db1.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        String empid = "";
        for (  DocumentChange snapshot : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges())
        {
            if (snapshot.getType()==DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                empid = snapshot.getDocument().getId();
                Log.d("employerid",empid);

            }
            FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            CollectionReference db2 =db.collection("Joboffers").document(empid).collection("Offers");
                    db2.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                    for (DocumentChange snapshot1 : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                        JO jo=new JO();
                        if (snapshot1.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                         jo = snapshot1.getDocument().toObject(JO.class);

                        String s=jo.getPoste().toString();
                        Log.d("poste",s);
                        postelist.add(jo);
                            jolistadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    }
                }

            });


        }

        MList.setAdapter(jolistadapter);



    }


});
```

here is my firestore collection:

[image]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j868j.jpg]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Consider adding the expected result of your code.

Comment: i m trying to view all the documents in my collection,so i used 2 snapshots

Comment: i get the the results i want in the logcat but i don't get them in my recycler view,i only get the first document

Comment: That sounds weird. If you put a breakpoint on `postelist.add(jo)` and run in a debugger, can you see it adding the additional items to the list?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen,the "Log.d" shows me that the values of the field "Poste" however in the emulator recyclerview i only get one

Comment: But if you check the size of `postelist`, does it contain multiple items. Because if so, the loading is correct and the problem is  likely in how `postelist` is used by your adapter.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, in the logcat postelist.size() returns 0

Comment: OK, thanks for checking. That means that your `postelist.add(jo)` never manages to add the item to the list. Set breakpoins inside your `onDataChange` and the step through it in a debugger to see why that is.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, when i put: "JO jo = offerSnapshot.toObject(JO.class);
Log.d("poste", jo.getPoste().toString()); postelist.add(jo);  jolistadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();Log.d("size", String.valueOf(postelist.size()));"   i get this in the logcat: "poste: professeur
size: 1
poste: rapporteur
size: 2
poste: encadreur
size: 3"

Comment: So they *are* being added to the list. As said, that means the problem is likely in how your adapter reads this list and presents it to the view. It's impossible to say more based on the information you shared. I recommend looking into [how to create a minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen,Thank you sir for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

*Not an answer to your actual problem yet, but just some basic code cleanup (that I can't fit in a comment).*

The way you determine the reference to the subcollection is overly complex. You can actually just get the subcollection from the `Document` in the first loop:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

CollectionReference jobOffersCollection = db.collection("Joboffers");

jobOffersCollection.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        for (DocumentChange snapshot : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
            if (snapshot.getType()==DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                Log.d("employerid", snapshot.getDocument().getId());
                CollectionReference offerCollection = snapshot.getDocument().getReference().collection("Offers");
                offerCollection.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {    
                    for (DocumentChange offerSnapshot : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                        if (n.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                            JO jo = snapshot1.getDocument().toObject(JO.class);

                            Log.d("poste", jo.getPoste().toString());
                            postelist.add(jo);
                            jolistadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        MList.setAdapter(jolistadapter);
    }
});
```

Note that I don't fully understand why you do things in the way you do. I'd recommend:

- Use `get` instead of `addSnapshotListener`, since your code seems focused on doing things one-time only anyway.
- Loop over `documentSnapshot.getDocuments()` instead of `getDocumentChanges()`, which would remove the needs for the very unusual `DocumentChange.Type.ADDED` check.

Comment: ,the "joboffers" collection is composed of many documents, each one's id is the same as the employer who saved it. however, each of the document will hold 2 collection (the"offers" and the"application");the first one is the list of offers the the employer post,the second one (still undone) will contain the list of application of the jobseekers.what i'm tryin to do is putting in a recyclerview all the documents in the "offer" collection of every single employer.